Is $l_1$-norm isometrically embeddible into Hilbert space?
I am reading Schoenberg's article "METRIC SPACES AND POSITIVE DEFINITE
FUNCTIONS". There he proves that $K({\mathbf x}, {\mathbf y}) = e^{-\gamma\|{\mathbf x}-{\mathbf y}\|_p^q}$ is a positive definite kernel for $p\geq q$ and $\gamma>0$, where $\|\cdot\|_p$ is a norm in $l_p$. What about the case $p=1,q=2$? Is it also positive definite?

If I remember well the statement s equivalent to conditional negative definitnesss of the function $|x-y|_1^2.$ Have tried three dimensional space ?

Yes. I think it is not CND, but wanted to verify my intuition.
